# Embedded .swf file too small (visually)

Tags: html, flash, embed

I've got an .swf file embedded into my HTML, but it comes up too small. This is the code I used:

`<embed src="example.com/file.swf" height="1136" width="640">`

So the issue is that instead of showing properly and full sized, it's down to something like 150px in height and scaled accordingly.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm using the HTML5 doctype, of course.

Thanks,
Ilian

Comment: Any more code you can show. And you are sure it is not just the white (default color) background of the flash that you see? Do you have a link / fiddle to show what is happening?

Comment: Never mind, I actually fixed it by simply adding a `style="height: 1136px"` to the `<embed>`. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

the problem comes from HTML5... i have the same problem, when i embed my swf (`<embed align="middle" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" height="100%" width="100%" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" quality="high" src="flash/index.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>`), the animation is too much reduced...

I had to delete html5 doctype and add this instead: `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">`. In this case my animation resize to 100% as i wanted !
Further more, to show my animation in my html5 website, i put the xhtml page in a resizable iframe... not a nice solution but efficiant :)

However i found even more solutions, for example swfobject : http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ but it did not work for me. if you try it, can you be so kind to tell me if works for you ?

Also i want to add to all of this that Flash does not work in mobile devices, nor in html5 with %, also it does not react to some script integrated in the website, i am having more and more the idea to abandon Flash completely...

Answer (score 0):

I have the final answer ! (if someone else will read this and be interested...) :

So, the embed code is enough for html5, as you wrote...

Put your embed code into a div (class="container" for example) :

```
<div class="container">
    <embed></embed>
</div>
```

Your css will be :

```
.container {
position: relative;
display: block;
height:1136px;
width:640px;
}
embed {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Sorry, i did not test it like this as the case of my animation is 100% of the screen size, but if there is a problem with the height, try "auto" or min-height as well !

What i did not know before is that the embed can be styled in %.